# Generators v/s Returning a List - Python

Tags: performance, list, python-3.x, generator

I was writing a program in Python which returns / retrieves all the adjacent elements in a given list. So I developed two functions:

One that stores all such adjacent values in a list and returns the list:

```
def ret_adj(data):
#adjs = []
visited = []
for i in data:

    if i in visited:
        #adjs.append(i)
        yield i
    else:
        visited.append(i)
    if data[data.index(i)+1] != i:
        del visited[:]

#return adjs
```

And one that yields the values:

```
    if i in visited:
        #adjs.append(i)
        yield i
    else:
        visited.append(i)
    if data[data.index(i)+1] != i:
        del visited[:]
```

So my question basically is, which method is more efficient? Returning all values as a list, or yielding them?

Comment: Neither of these approaches appear to use `return`.

Comment: You're using `visited = []` in a manner that ought to use a **`set`** really.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, a `generator` will be more efficient, especially for large data sets.

On the other hand, if your usual method of processing the data is to immediately turn the `generator` into a `list`, then you would be better off just returning the list in the first place.